# Laravel 5.3 correct initialize of the guard in middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I try to make a custom middleware for authentication, everything is correct but not $guard, how can I initizalize it correctly?

My code looks like:

```
Auth::guard($guard)->guest()
```

I tried to initialize guard with following methods, but all this is not correct:

```
1. protected $guard = null;
2.     public function __construct($guard)
    {
        $guard = null;
    }
3.     public function __construct($guard)
    {
        protected = $guard;
    }
```

But I get there this error message:

```
Undefined variable: guard
```

What I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to define Guards to your controllers:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('guard-name');
}
```